# How can I train myself to hear the difference between C (/'si:/) and Z (/'zi:/)?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

When you hear Americans [spell their names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_alphabet#Letter_names),

- C is pronounced as `/'si:/`, and
- Z is pronounced as `/'zi:/`.

To me, both sound the same. What can I do to hear a difference?

In English language classes, this issue never came up, because we were taught British English, where Z is pronounced as `/ˈzɛd/`.

**Research I've done**: Apparently, /s/ is the [voiceless alveolar fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_alveolar_fricative) and /z/ is the [voiced alveolar fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_alveolar_fricative). I tried to find words in my native language (Austrian German) using /s/ and /z/, but, apparently, /z/ [is voiceless in the southern German variants](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimmhafter_alveolarer_Frikativ), so that doesn't help either.

Comment: I am not native, but I do not share the same problem. I think Z is conspicuous. What about, /z/ sound at beginning of **sie**?

Comment: In English, s and z are always differentiated, apart from at the ends of some plurals. Check out this word, for example: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/zest

Comment: Musik. Fluessig.

Comment: @TRomano I think OP's problem is word-onset /sV/. I can't think of an instance where the [s]-[z] contrast there would be phonemic in German.

Comment: @StoneyB: How does OP (or do Austrians) pronounce  *Szenen*?

Comment: With the /s/ followed by /ts/ ?

Comment: @TRomano I imagine so; I don't remember the word coming up in schoolboy conversation 50+ years ago! But that doesn't involve an [s]-[z] contrast.

Comment: I wonder if their bees sound like snakes.

Comment: @TRomano Bees *brummen* and snakes *zischen*, so there's a definite contrast in degree of voicing!

Comment: @StoneyB: I know diddly about this phenomenon. Is it possible for our Austrian friend to practice making the buzzing sound of a bee, b-zzzzzz only without the /b/ and thereby attune his ear?  The phoneme in question is just a very brief timeslice of that buzzing sound.

Comment: @TRomano But first he has to recognize when he's saying it right.

Comment: Z is less common than C in English, so if you can't tell, it's better to assume it's C.  It would help to become familiar with the spelling of at least the most common American first and middle names as well, so your mind has information to draw up when confused in the future.

Comment: @StoneyB: yes, he couldn't do it without some kind of help. Maybe he could listen again and again to the Google Translate voice saying **sip zip**.  There's a hissing with **sip** and not with **zip**. Maybe his ear could detect that eventually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Practise, practise, practise, and don't just listen, try to do it yourself.

Think about the difference between /f/ (as in *fünf*) and /v/ (as in *weiß*). What do you do differently when you pronounce /v/? Can you do that whilst saying /s/?

Practise.

Phonetics sites might help you. The wikipedia articles are good and contain sound samples. Personally I always liked [this one](http://www.paulmeier.com/consonants/) but there might be others.

But anyway, if all else fails, [you can always ask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet),

> Sorry, I didn't catch that, was that 'c' for 'Charlie' or 'z' for 'zulu'?

Answer (score 14):

The problem, as you suggest, is that

(1) in Standard German the sound [z] is most often encountered as an 'allophone' (environmentally determined variant) of /s/; in those instances where the [s]-[z] contrast is phonemic, [s] is orthographically marked as <ss> (eg., *weise - weisse*).

BUT

(2) In your dialect of German /s/ is almost always realized as [s], regardless of environment; in effect, Austrian German does not have a [z] sound.

However: when I attended the Innsbruck Realgymnasium in '62-63 there was regular instruction in speaking "proper" Hochdeutsch.

If that was still the case in your schooling, this may help: the difference between 'C' /'si:/ and 'Z' /'zi:/ is the difference between the way you ordinarily say *Sie* and the way you were taught you *should* say *Sie*.

Answer (score 3):

Please compare the German "Sie" (you) and the second syllable of the French "Merci" (thanks). Are they pronounced the same in your area?

Assuming that you hear a difference, then "Sie" sounds like the name of the letter "Z" and the "cie" in "Merci" sounds like the name of the letter "C".

Comment: The [German Wikipedia page about the voiced consonant](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimmhafter_alveolarer_Frikativ) says: "*(kommt in den südlichen Varietäten nicht vor, dort stimmlos)*", which translates as "*(does not exist in the Southern variants, it's voiceless there)*".

Comment: It escaped my attention, but now I see it's there... Editing my answer - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's true that when naming the letters of the alphabet, the British ***call*** the letter Z, "Zed".  But in both British and American English, the phoneme "z" /'zi:/, is pronounced differently from a soft "c" /'si:/.

Your native dialect may not have a phoneme similar to the English /'zi:/, but you certainly have the sound.  If you've ever had your hair cut with an electric hair trimmer, then you've heard the English /'zi:/ --- "buzzzzzzzzz".

A "soft c" (/'si:/) in English is pronounced like the English "s". It sounds like air escaping a punctured tire, and that's basically how you make the sound.  To make a soft /c/ -- hold your mouth slightly open, press your tongue to the roof of your mouth, with the tip against your upper front teeth, so that you can not exhale through your mouth.  Now drop the tip of your tongue to let air escape, and finally feel your throat just below your jaw - if your vocal cords are not vibrating, that's an English /'si:/

To voice an English "z" (/'zi:/), hold your tongue similar to /'si:/, but drop the tip of your tongue to touch your lower front teeth.  The big difference is the "voiced" part - when you exhale, the vocal cords vibrate (remember the electric hair trimmer :-).

The key is the vibrating vocal cords.  Hold your fingers to your throat, when you practice -- vibrating = /'zi:/ ("fuzzy") --- not vibrating = /'si:/ ("fussy").

Some people soften their z's, so that they almost sound like a /'si:/.  But remember those electric hair trimmers and you'll be buzzzzzzing away in no time.